# Как изменить репозиторий на другой ветке, чтобы другой человек это увидел?

Tags: git

Работаю в проекте. Т.к я новичок, чтобы не сломать ничего, сделал себе отдельную ветку. Теперь, собственно, вопрос: я изменил некоторый файлы, теперь, чтобы другой человек мог посмотреть это, что мне нужно сделать? Просто коммитить? Или пушить тоже нужно? (работаю в pycharm, там есть вариант только коммит или пуш+коммит. На мо. ветку в pycharm я переключился)

Comment: Репозиторий у вас, скорее всего, удалённый. А значит, надо пушить. А он вытянет через pull.

Comment: И как-то у вас заголовок с текстом вопроса не коррелирует.